about the expansion of the universe. 7 heavens
in Islam we have 7 heavens
if the universe is expanding, is the first heaven expanding? the first heaven does not go beyond the second heaven? thank you

In Islam we have 7 Heavens (and probably 7 Earths) of which seemingly all the stars (which you may call it the visible universe) belong to only the first Heaven:

فَقَضَاهُنَّ سَبْعَ سَمَاوَاتٍ فِي يَوْمَيْنِ وَ أَوْحَيٰ فِي كُلِّ سَمَاءٍ أَمْرَهَا وَ زَيَّنَّا السَّمَاءَ الدُّنْيَا ‍بِمَصَابِيحَ ...
So He completed them as seven firmaments in two Days, and He assigned
to each heaven its duty and command. And We adorned the lower heaven
with lights ...
إِنَّا زَيَّنَّا السَّمَاءَ الدُّنْيَا بِزِينَةٍ الْكَوَاكِبِ
Indeed, We have adorned the nearest heaven with an adornment of stars

However,I have not seen a single Hadeeth that insists on the Dunya Heaven being equal to the first Heaven, although it is usually understood this way as far as I have seen.
